# Is possible use batch Script to get OpenGL Version?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, opengl, version

i wanna know if possible, with a Batch Script or another Windows (XP , Seven, Eight, Ten) or Script compatible for get the current drivers OpenGL Version.

I wanna adapt part of my bash script to Windows :

```
#!/bin/bash

# 
# Autor     :   Inukaze ( Venezuela )
# Site      :   http://inukaze.wordpress.com
# E-Mail    :   inukaze.otaku@gmail.com
# License   :   GPL 3
#
#

# Obtener la Architecture
Architecture=$(uname -m)
case "$Architecture" in
    x86)    Architecture="x32"                          ;;
    i?86)   Architecture="x32"                          ;;
    amd64)  Architecture="x64"                          ;;
    x86_64) Architecture="x64"                          ;;
    * ) echo "Your Architecture Detected $Architecture -> Its not supported"    ;;
esac


# Detect OpenGL Version :
OpenGLV=$(glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version" | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -c 5- | rev)

# Use the version of GzDoom according to the OpenGL version detected
case "$OpenGLV" in
1)
    echo
    echo "OpenGL 1 Detected"
    echo
    echo "Using GzDoom 1.8.6"
    Version=1.8.6
    if  [ "$Architecture" = "x32" ]; then
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH="Gnu/Linux/$Version/lib32"
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            Engine="Gnu/Linux/$Version/gzdoom.$Architecture"
    elif    [ "$Architecture" = "x64" ]; then
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH="Gnu/Linux/$Version/lib64"
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            Engine="Gnu/Linux/$Version/gzdoom.$Architecture"
    else
        echo "Your Architecture Detected $Architecture -> Its not supported"
    fi
    ;;

2) 
    echo
    echo "OpenGL 2 Detected"
    echo
    echo "Using GzDoom GzDoom 1.9.1"
    Version=1.9.1
    if  [ "$Architecture" = "x32" ]; then
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH="Gnu/Linux/$Version/lib32"
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            Engine="Gnu/Linux/$Version/gzdoom.$Architecture"
    elif    [ "$Architecture" = "x64" ]; then
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH="Gnu/Linux/$Version/lib64"
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            Engine="Gnu/Linux/$Version/gzdoom.$Architecture"
    else
        echo "Your Architecture Detected $Architecture -> Its not supported"
    fi
    ;;

3)  
    echo
    echo "OpenGL 3 Detected"
    echo
    echo "Using GzDoom GzDoom 2.1.1"
    Version=2.1.1
    if  [ "$Architecture" = "x32" ]; then
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH="Gnu/Linux/$Version/lib32"
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            Engine="Gnu/Linux/$Version/gzdoom.$Architecture"
    elif    [ "$Architecture" = "x64" ]; then
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH="Gnu/Linux/$Version/lib64"
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
            Engine="Gnu/Linux/$Version/gzdoom.$Architecture"
    else
        echo "Your Architecture Detected $Architecture -> Its not supported"
    fi
    ;;

*) 
    echo "OpenGL version not determined"
    ;;
esac

    export Architectures
    for Architectures in $Architecture; do
        test -x ./$Engine || continue
        exec ./$Engine "$@"
    done

echo "Could not start GzDoom" >&2
```

But i dont know a method for get OpenGL Version on Batch Script or another Script. or if someone know a simple command line tool for i get it and use in the new script i wanna adapt to windows compatible.

Comment: Is your intention that you will build the program on the machine that will eventually run it?

Comment: Yes, not only on my pc, in anothers pcs, with diferents GPUs with OpenGL 1.0 , OpenGL 2.0, and OpenGL 3.0

Comment: AFAIK you need some utility. Either create simple .exe or google existing one. GLEW is shipped with visualinfo which outputs something like `OpenGL version string: 4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4061` among other information.

Comment: Please refrain from using word such as "wanna", "dude" and other slang words, as it can be very confusing to decipher the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL version can only determined at runtime, based on hardware/driver capabilities.

The same driver may report 3.3 on one GPU because it does not support all 4.0 features but 4.x on another. There is no way to know this without running something. What is worse, the driver's version string has historically been misleading, with some drivers claiming GL 2.0 without support for non-power-of-two textures.

Software should not infer anything from reported driver version, well-written software will check extension support at run-time and either use a fallback or fail-fast at initialization.

You may need to write a very simple program to create a context and do this, you certainly will not be doing it from a batch script unless you rely on non-portable stuff like `glxinfo`.